# How to fix “prevented a sign-in attempt” from Gmail on server (C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, gmail, asp.net-core-2.0

when my asp's service sends email by IEmailSender, sometime google blocks my service. This is my configuration:

```
public Task SendEmailAsync(string email, string subject, string message)
    {
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(_configuration["MailSettings:Server"])
        {
            EnableSsl = bool.Parse(_configuration["MailSettings:EnableSsl"]),
            UseDefaultCredentials = false,
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential(_configuration["MailSettings:UserName"], _configuration["MailSettings:Password"]),
            Port = int.Parse(_configuration["MailSettings:Port"]),


        };



        MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage
        {
            From = new MailAddress(_configuration["MailSettings:FromEmail"], _configuration["MailSettings:FromName"]),
        };
        mailMessage.To.Add(email);
        mailMessage.Body = message;
        mailMessage.Subject = subject;
        mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
        client.Send(mailMessage);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
```

[image]

[image]

And google make me can not send email sometimes:
[image]

[image]

When I allow this server, my service can send email normally.  After short time, google blocks me again and again.I want my service can send an email everytime no need to check mail and allow this server to use my email account. Please help me. Thanks so much.

Comment: I think you better use [Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/dotnet) for this.

Comment: I prefer to use Sendgrid or AWS smpt details o send emails.

Comment: If you want to stick with google mail, please have look https://stackoverflow.com/a/25216277/10018200

Comment: @vasily.sib thank for your ideas. I will follow this solution

Comment: @Abhijith thank for your advise. I will try some free solution first.